# Upgradation in .Net version at domain side

Tags: .net

My application is using .Net version 3.5 edition 2 and client is using Windows server 2008 at domain side. Now they want to upgrade the server to windows server 2016. Please suggest me if it will affect the application or not.?

Comment: No, it won't affect your application

Comment: Thank you ... But one more thing Do I need a hotfix in it?

Comment: I do not think so because every next version is backward compatible. But still one can be sure only after practically implementing it, so you should go with upgradation and then see what happens.